# Why is this Nginx setup not caching responses?

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I have Nginx sitting in front of `gunicorn`, which in turn sits in front of a `django` application.

The core question is "Why are my responses not being cached?" However, I'm pretty green at this, so here are my assumptions on what *should* happen (in case my core understanding is flawed).

Request `A` hits `Nginx` asking for, say, some `json` from a REST service. Nginx doesn't have this in its cache, so it passes it onto `Gunicorn/Django`. A response is generated, passed back through Nginx, where it is cached, and finally back out to the client.

Then!

Request `B` comes in asking for the same resource. Nginx has it in its cache and thus serves it directly, never hitting the django application.

Based on that assumption, and after much reading I ended up with this minimal nginx configuration in my `sites-enabled`:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx keys_zone=one:20m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri";


server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    proxy_cache one;

    location / {
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

This code is based on the docs for [nginx caching](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/caching/), and the tutorial [here](https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching/).

If I test a few requests, I get this response:

```
curl -X GET -I http://localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 06 May 2015 01:35:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=b6UG5X4ZlGwVUYfHSIkq4PKBIxicpWxc; expires=Wed, 04-May-2016 01:35:38 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
```

Note: I think the cookie is fine since I don't include it in the `cache_key` directive. I could be wrong though.

Despite numerous request for the same resource, I never get a cache hit. Further, no cache files are written in the `proxy_cache_path` directory.

Could someone point me towards why no responses are being cached?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to cache an entity which holds a `Set-Cookie` header is quite a bad idea. This is [natively forbidden](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers) by nginx unless told with the `proxy_ignore_headers` directive.

This header ignored plus the `Vary: Cookie` header in replies would make your cache quite ineffective since a sole resource will have as many cache entries as the amount of visitors asking for it.

Also note that the `Vary` header is taken into account in the caching algorithm since version `1.7.7` only. Using a previous nginx version with `proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;` would result in massive cookie duplication as the `Set-Cookie` header from the cached reply would be sent back to all requests hitting the cache entry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the issue is that the upstream server is just not sending response that contain an expiration date (`Expires:`) or a cache validator (for instance, `Last-Modified:`). (The cookie expiration time has nothing to do with caching.)

The [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4) says:

> If there is neither a cache validator nor an explicit expiration time associated with a response, **we do not expect it to be cached,** but certain caches MAY violate this expectation (for example, when little or no network connectivity is available).

(Emphasis added.)

So it looks like your Django setup does not have caching turned on. I suggest you turn on [per-site caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache). If you do this, Django will generate in its response the headers that Nginx needs for caching.

Another option would be to use the `proxy_cache_valid` option in your Nginx configuration. I used a setup similar to yours and replicated the behavior you got, then I added `proxy_cache_valid any 5m;` which tells Nginx to cache responses that have any status code (`any`) for 5 minutes `5m`. Once, I did that, I got cache hits.